# SQL how to get all images to show for respective units

Tags: php, mysql

[image: monticello]

[image]

My question is how to get multiple images to display next to their  respective units information. I am able to print out all the images below but unable to get each listing to print out its respective images. originally i was trying to do it as a single query but it was only printing out the same image multiple times so i tried to do two seperate queries but it did not work, how can i fix it?

```
// Define the query but only for info:
  $querystats = 'SELECT 8052monticello.UNIT, 8052monticello.SIZE, 8052monticello.id, 8052monticello.PRICE';
  $querystats.= ' FROM 8052monticello'; 

if ($r = mysqli_query($connection, $querystats)) { // Run the query.
    // Retrieve and print every record:
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {

    if ($row['PRICE']){
        // echo "<img src='images/".$row['image_name']."' width='100'>";

        print "<p><h3>{$row['UNIT']} Unit #</h3>    
        {$row['SIZE']} Sq Feet<br>
        {$row['PRICE']} Monthly rent<br>
        <a href=\"edit_UNIT.php?id={$row['id']}\">Edit</a>
        <a href=\"delete_UNIT.php?id={$row['id']}\">Delete</a>
        </p><hr>\n";
    }
    }
} 
//get the images
  $queryimage = 'SELECT photos.image_name, photos.fk_unit, 8052monticello.UNIT';
  $queryimage.= ' FROM photos, 8052monticello';
  $queryimage.= ' WHERE photos.fk_unit= 8052monticello.unit';



if ($r = mysqli_query($connection, $queryimage)) { // Run the query.
    // Retrieve and print every record:
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
    if ($row['image_name']){
    echo "<img src='images/".$row['image_name']."' width='100'>";
     }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) in your query to join both the monticello and photos table:

```
$query = '
SELECT 
    m.UNIT, m.SIZE, m.id, m.PRICE,
    p.image_name
FROM 8052monticello m
INNER JOIN photos p ON p.fk_unit = m.unit';
```

Now you have access to `$row['image_name']` in your loop.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
    if ($row['PRICE']){
        print "<img src=\"images/{$row['image_name']}\" width='100'>
        <p><h3>{$row['UNIT']} Unit #</h3>    
        {$row['SIZE']} Sq Feet<br>
        {$row['PRICE']} Monthly rent<br>
        <a href=\"edit_UNIT.php?id={$row['id']}\">Edit</a>
        <a href=\"delete_UNIT.php?id={$row['id']}\">Delete</a>
        </p><hr>\n";
    }
}
```

**Updated:** For each row, images are fetched from the database.

```
$query = "SELECT 
      m.UNIT, m.SIZE, m.id, m.PRICE
    FROM 8052monticello m "; 
$res = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if (!$res){
   // throw error here
}
$query2 = "SELECT p.image_name 
     FROM photos p 
     WHERE p.fk_unit = '%s' ";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $res2 = mysqli_query($connection, sprintf($query2, $row["UNIT"]));
    while($img = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res2)) {
       echo "<img src=\"images/{$img['image_name']}\" width='100'>";
    }
    print "<p><h3>{$row['UNIT']} Unit #</h3>    
        {$row['SIZE']} Sq Feet<br>
        {$row['PRICE']} Monthly rent<br>
        <a href=\"edit_UNIT.php?id={$row['id']}\">Edit</a>
        <a href=\"delete_UNIT.php?id={$row['id']}\">Delete</a>
        </p><hr>\n";
}
```

Comment: Ok so as i understand i should not try to do two seperate queries, but only run one query, and the $query variable used in your example would replace the two seperate $queryimage and $query stats variables i am using. I should shorthand the table names as you did in your example?

Comment: Yes, and I added the while loop for you to see.

Comment: this is the same query i am running but it needs to display the unit only ONCE along with ALL the photos connected to it.. right now is printing out the unit every time there is an image associated with it.  It should print out each listing only once and then loop through the photos that correspond to that listing. Also i was just curious how can i attach screenshots in my reply to you? and why I recieved a -1 ?

Comment: In that case you'll need two queries, like you had before. Except you'll use the result of the first, to build the second query.

Comment: The best comparison would be like a nested loop. where the outer loop would be each row of info in the 8052 table and the inner loop would be to run through all of the images in the photos table that are associated with that particular row from the 8052 table.. I know how to run a regular nested loop in php but im lost here. Can you please show me the solution how to do this?